# jetty: can I specify another ip address in start,ini for http connection?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

jetty: can I add another public ip address in start.ini for http connection without creating another http connector  as below ?

```
jetty.http.host=192.168.1.121,192.168.1.122
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices.

1) Use the virtual interface `0.0.0.0` to bind to all interfaces on your machine.

2) Create specific connectors for each interface you want to bind to.

Comment: do you know how to add another connector for ssl ? I replicate the add connector block in jetty-ssl.xml changing the ip address, it throws exception. While it works fine with the same process for http.